# How to Set Key in Multidimensional subarrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
//$mystring_val
$string_val=56149-1853,55847-1588 ;

$newarr= explode(",",$string_val);
print_r ($newarr);
$result = array();
$res = array();
foreach ($newarr as $key=>$value){

    $res['multicheque_array_items'][]= explode("-",$value);
 }

echo "<br/><br/>====<br/>";      
print_r ($res);
```

**My Output is :**

```
Array
(
    [multicheque_array_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 56149
                    [1] => 1853
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 55847
                    [1] => 1588
                )

        )

)
```

**But I want output like this**

```
Array
(
    [multidimensional] => Array
        (
            [paynum] => Array
                (
                    [payid] => 56149
                    [itemid] => 1853
                )

        )

    [multidimensional] => Array
        (
            [paynum] => Array
                (
                    [payid] => 55847
                    [itemid] => 1588
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: use $arr=array_fill_keys ( array $keys , mixed $value )

Comment: this key `paynum` will appear in 'multidimensional' again and again then you will have only one value,all will be replaced by the last value .

Comment: i just want all the values @RajeevRanjan have any solution for replacing numeric index with individual key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $string_val='56149-1853,55847-1588' ;
 $newarr= explode(",",$string_val);
 foreach ($newarr as $key=>$value){
    $temp = explode("-",$value);
    for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++){
        if($i==0)
            $res['multidimensional_'.$key]['paynum']['payid'] = $temp[0];
        else
            $res['multidimensional_'.$key]['paynum']['itemid'] = $temp[1];
    }   
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r ($res);
```

It will show output as,

```
Array
(
    [multidimensional_0] => Array
        (
            [paynum] => Array
                (
                    [payid] => 56149
                    [itemid] => 1853
                )

        )

    [multidimensional_1] => Array
        (
            [paynum] => Array
                (
                    [payid] => 55847
                    [itemid] => 1588
                )

        )

)
```

Fixed your code..!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you can use this :-

```
$arr=array('multicheque_array_items' => array(
        array(56149,1853),array(55847,1588)
       )

);
$out=array();
$keys=array('payid','itemid');
foreach($arr['multicheque_array_items'] as $items){
   $out['multicheque_array_items'][]=array_combine($keys,$items);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Output : -

```
Array
(
    [multicheque_array_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [payid] => 56149
                    [itemid] => 1853
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [payid] => 55847
                    [itemid] => 1588
                )

        )

)
```